# Why does CRM.url give different results in WordPress and Drupal?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why the JavaScript function `CRM.url` gives different results depending on CMS. Can anyone explain?

For example this code:

```
CRM.url('civicrm/payment/ipn/test', null, 'front')
```

In WordPress it returns the complete URL with the domain:

`http://wpmaster.localhost:7979/civicrm/civicrm/payment/ipn/test/`

Whereas in Drupal in returns the URL without the domain:

`/civicrm/payment/ipn/test`

This inconsistency feels wrong. Is it a bug in CiviCRM?

For context I'm looking at this issue: https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless/issues/97

Answer (score 0):

I believe the third parameter should be boolean not string, 1 or 0/ true or false

Comment: Don't think so. `js/crm.ajax.js` defines it as 'front' or 'back' (if `mode` is not given, then it is set to one of those strings based on config); 'front' and 'back' are keys which are used to fetch from the `tplURL` var.

Comment: Here's the code reference: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/js/crm.ajax.js#L10